# Construct a random permutation from a random function?

Tags: randomness, pseudo-random-function, permutation

How can we construct a (pseudo) random permutation from a (pseudo) random function ?

I've seen a method from Luby-Rackoff which allows to construct a PRP of length $2N$ from a PRF of input/output length $N$. Is there a method to keep the same length $N$ ?

I'm looking for a method that has better security bounds than truncating the output of a $N$-bits output pseudorandom function to obtain an output of $N/2$-bits and using the Luby-Rackoff construction.

Comment: Since a truncation of a PRF is still a PRF, you can trivially use the above construction where you truncate the PRF to N/2.

Comment: Thank you CodesInChaos. Effectively, but I would like a method without truncating a PRF, for reason of a tight trade-off between security and efficiency.

Comment: If this is a practical problem, you should take a step back and describe your actual requirements.

Comment: In the current form it's a purely theoretical problem. If this is based on a practical problem, then my impression is that your approach is misguided, i.e. that you suffer from the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Dingo13, no, you haven't given the requirements.  You said you wanted something different from (Luby-Rackoff blah), but you haven't said why.  If that solution wasn't acceptable, that is a sign that you need to go back and revisit your requirements.  If it wasn't secure enough, then ask yourself: *how* secure does my solution need to be?  What is the security metric I care about?  Then, edit the question to describe the *real* requirements.  If you just say "I want a solution, any other solution than (that one CodesInChaos described)", then you have a nonsense question.

Comment: (cont.) For instance, if CodesInChaos's construction is not secure enough, what *would* be good enough?  Would security up to $O(2^{2N/3})$ be good enough?  Do you need security at the $O(2^N)$ level?  How many chosen plaintexts/ciphertext queries $q$ do you think an adversary might be able to mount, in your situation?  How much computation time might an adversary be able to spend?  What is the actual value of $N$, in your scenario?  These questions should help you make your requirements more precise.  Then, edit the question to answer these questions.

Answer (score 3):

There are so many possible solutions here.  Without giving your requirements more carefully, it's just not possible to tell what would count as a valid solution.  Here are a bunch of schemes that offer better security than simply truncating to $N/2$ bits and applying 4 rounds of Luby-Rackoff:

- For instance, one approach is to truncate the random function to $N/2$ bits, then use 6 or more rounds of the Luby-Rackoff construction.  Paterin has a paper at FSE 1998 that apparently proves that 6 rounds gives security for up to $O(2^{3N/8})$ chosen plaintext/ciphertext queries.  He also has a [later paper](http://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2003/27290510/27290510.pdf) at Crypto 2003 that apparently proves that 10 rounds is enough for security for up to $O(2^{N(1-\epsilon)/2})$ chosen plaintext/ciphertext queries.  Don't ask me to explain the proofs; I don't understand them.  I am not aware of any concrete-security versions of these results, so it's hard to know exactly how much security this gives you in practice.
- Another approach is to truncate the random function to 1 bit of output (and $N-1$ input bits), then build a maximally unbalanced Feistel network that uses $4N$ rounds.  Naor and Reingold [showed](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~naor/PAPERS/lr.ps) (Journal of Cryptology, Jan 1999) that this will give security for up to $O(2^{N/2})$ chosen plaintext/ciphertext queries.  (Technically speaking, their result assumed that you used a pairwise-independent permutation, then $2N$ rounds of unbalanced Feistel, than another pairwise-independent permutation, so if you really care about provable security, you could use that: but I suspect their results would likely apply to $4N$ rounds of unbalanced Feistel as well.)
- Even better yet, if you do enough rounds of maximally unbalanced Feistel network, you can get arbitrarily close to $O(2^N)$ security.  Truncate the random function to one that takes $N-1$ input bits and has 1 output bit, and use it in an unbalanced Feistel network.  Morris, Rogaway, and Stegers [proved](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/thorp.pdf) at Crypto 2009 that, if you do $4RN$ rounds of this, you get security up to $O(2^{N(1-1/R)})$ chosen plaintext/ciphertext queries.  For instance, if you do $40N$ rounds, you get security up to something like $O(2^{0.9N})$ chosen plaintext/ciphertext queries.  That's a very impressive result.  If maximizing security is your goal, this might be your best bet.
- Another approach is to truncate the random function to one on $N/2$ bits, then apply a suitable Benes network construction.  Aiello and Venkatesan proved in Eurocrypt 1996 that, with four rounds, this gives you security for up to $O(2^{N/2})$ chosen plaintext/ciphertext queries.

One keyword that may help you find still more results is "Luby-Rackoff beyond the birthday bound".

Answer (score 2):

There is a [generic construction](http://www.bolet.org/~pornin/2007-fse-granboulan+pornin.pdf) called Permutator, which can turn a seekable stream of random bits into a permutation. A "seekable stream" is obtained from a PRF by applying the PRF on an input index.

This construction works with any target space (it generates a permutation of a space of size $n$ where $n$ is not necessarily a power of 2). Also it is "perfect", meaning that every possible permutation of the space of size $n$ can be selected, with probability exactly $1/n!$, contrary to, for instance, Feistel schemes which necessarily implement even permutations only. This can have some some importance when targeting a permutation in a small domain (e.g. a permutation of all sequences of 8 decimal digits).

Unfortunately, implementing Permutator, as described in the article, implies doing some computations in arbitrary precision arithmetics, which is doable but very slow. This is a consequence of the sampling method (based on rejection) for the hypergeometric distribution, that we used: that method is unbiased but expensive.

Answer (score 1):

There is a recent paper by Hoang, Morris & Rogaway which proposes an alternative construction of PRPs from PRFs.

> Viet Tung Hoang, Ben Morris, Phillip Rogaway, [An Enciphering Scheme Based on a Card Shuﬄe](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.1176v1.pdf), CRYPTO 2012

The construction has a few nice features. <strike>First, the domain of the PRF is preserved, which is one of your requirements.</strike> Second, it provides security beyond the birthday bound. The construction is still quite simple, but the tradeoff compared to Luby-Rackoff is an increase in the number of rounds (logarithmic).

You can see the slides & video of the associated talk at the [CRYPTO 2012 program page](http://www.iacr.org/conferences/crypto2012/program-2012.html).

**edit**: Hm, actually this construction uses a *one-bit PRF* to build a PRP. Still, you could think of an $n$-bit PRF as $n$ distinct 1-bit PRFs, and use a different bit for each round of this construction. Certainly $n$ rounds would be plenty. Also, you have $n$ distinct 1-bit PRFs that are all *keyed by the same key*. So your key size would not increase going from PRF to PRP (as it does in Luby-Rackoff -- you need independent keys for each round of the Feistel network).

Comment: One shouldn't do $n$ rounds, since one also needs $\:K_1,...,K_r\:$. $\;\;\;$